# What could be the reason for a URL to open in-browser on first open, but on every subsequent open it opens in-app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, kotlin

What could be the reason for a URL to open in-browser on first open, but on every subsequent open it opens in-app?

I tried creating a new **React Native** application and it worked just fine, so it must be some sort of setting that I've included in order to use some other library.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you're reffering to `Deep Linking`

**Deep linking** in React Native allows you to link to specific content or screens within a mobile app directly from a web URL or another app. It provides a seamless way to navigate to and interact with app content, enhancing user experience and engagement.

**Example**
Imagine you have a news app developed in React Native, and you want users to be able to access a specific news article by clicking a link. With deep linking, you can achieve this. Here's how it works:

Learn more:

[React native Handling Deep Links - [https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking]](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#handling-deep-links)

[React Navigation - [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/]](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)